# How To Use Gradiant Color in Flutter Range Slider

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFWhY.png)

I want this type Of range Slider in My U.i

**i want affectable solution with out any library**

Comment: refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64212083/13997210) answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Slider you can't pass gradient Directly because Slider just Accept Color.

but you could add Container and graident Color then add your Slider

```
...

     Container(
        height: 10,
        width: 200,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),

          // gradient colors
          gradient: LinearGradient(colors: [
            Colors.red,
            Colors.blue,
          ]),
        ),
        child: SliderTheme(
          data: SliderThemeData(
            overlayShape: SliderComponentShape.noOverlay,
          ),
          child: Slider(
           
            // you have to transparent colors to show gradient colors
            activeColor: Colors.transparent,
            inactiveColor: Colors.transparent,
            thumbColor: Colors.green,
            onChanged: (v) => setState(() => value = v),
            value: value,
          ),
        ),
```

if you find any grammer mistake in my english or my solution feel free to edit it :)