# I want to create a slider UI to manipulate opacity

Tags: flutter, flutter-design, flutter-slider

[image]

I would like to make such a slider.
The color OK be fixed at black.

### The current code is as follows

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Slider(
        activeColor: ColorManager.blueColor,
        value: _opacity,
        min: 0.0,
        max: 1.0,
        onChanged: updateOpacity,
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Your question is much like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64199117/flutter-slider-with-gradient
They want to create a slider with linear gradient color. You can try to change the linear gradient color with linear gradient transparent. Hope this help :)